# Can I publish only one project in my eclipse workspace to the web server?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, tcserver

I have an eclipse (actually STS springsource tool set) workspace which contains several projects - each one is a separate web site (all hosted on the same server).
I set all building and publishing options to be manual (I don't like automatic).
I have 2 sites(projects) set to publish on the fabric tomcat dev edition that comes with eclipse.
In order to publish them after making changes, I right click on the "vm fabric tc" and select publish - but this publishes both sites and takes longer.
Is there a method where I can somehow tell eclipse to publish each time only one specific site ?